# Exclude dates based on a list from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a `pd.to_datetime` column df, where the column day is: df['Date'].dt.day:

```
Day
01.01.2020
02.01.2020
...
```

And I have another dataframe with a `pd.to_datetime`column closeddays:

```
Closed
01.01.2020
31.01.2020
```

How can I exclude every row which is on the closed list, i tried:

```
df = df.loc[~df['Day'].isin([closeddays['Closed']])]
```

which leads to an error: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

How can i get the outcome:

```
Day
02.01.2020
...
```

Comment: `df = df.loc[~df['Day'].isin(closeddays['Closed'])]`. You don't have to put it in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this -

```
df = df[~(df['Date'].isin(closeddays['Closed'].dt.date.tolist()))]
```